# Creating schema not successful in Solr

Tags: solr, schema

I have the data ready for index now, it is a json file:

```
{"122": "20180320-08:08:35.038", "49": "VIPER", "382": "0", "151": "1.0", "9": "653", "10071": "20180320-08:08:35.088", "15": "JPY", "56": "XSVC", "54": "1", "10202": "APMKTMAKING", "10537": "XOSE", "10217": "Y", "48": "179492540", "201": "1", "40": "2", "8": "FIX.4.4", "167": "OPT", "421": "JPN", "10292": "115", "10184": "337912000000002", "456": "101", "11210": "337912000000002", "1133": "G", "10515": "178", "10": "200", "11032": "-1", "10436": "20180320-08:08:35.038", "10518": "178", "11": "337912000000002", "75": "20180320", "10005": "178", "10104": "Y", "35": "RIO", "10208": "APAC.VIPER.OOE", "59": "0", "60": "20180320-08:08:35.088", "528": "P", "581": "13", "1": "TEST", "202": "25375.0", "455": "179492540", "55": "JNI253D8.OS", "100": "XOSE", "52": "20180320-08:08:35.088", "10241": "viperooe", "150": "A", "10039": "viperooe", "39": "A", "10438": "RIO.4.5", "38": "1", "37": "337912000000002", "372": "D", "660": "102", "44": "2.0", "10066": "20180320-08:08:35.038", "29": "4", "50": "JPNIK01", "22": "101"}
```

You can inspect the json here: https://jsonformatter.org/

I need to create index and enable searching on tags: 37(order_id), 75(trade_date) and 10242 (where available, this sample message doesn't have it)

My understanding is I need to create the file managed-schema, I added two fields as below:

```
<field name="order_id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="trd_date" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Then I go back to Solr Admin, I don't see the two new fields in Schema section

Anything I am missing here? and once the two fields are put in the managed-schema, can I add the json file through upload in Solr Admin?

Thank you very much.

Update: I have 100+ fields in the data to be index'ed, the data is a json file format. I wonder what is the best practice to create the schema file, thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't have to create the file yourself, that should be created by Solr (since it's a _managed_ schema). If you're manually editing the file, you have to reload the collection/core or restart Solr afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. The schema for the data could end up with 100+ fields, that's why I test it out with two fields here. Restart the Solr shows the new fields.

Comment: Hi MatsLindh, would you like to put your comment as the answer, I will accept it as an answer, I cannot accept a comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to create the file yourself, that should be created by Solr (since it's a managed schema). If you're manually editing the file, you have to reload the collection/core or restart Solr afterwards.

Otherwise you can use [the Schema API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html) to add or change fields. If you're running in a cloud context / cluster, you'll want to use the Schema API so that your changes can be spread across all nodes (and your schema would live in Zookeeper in that case anyway).